# Will APNS token still work after getting a FCM token

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications

Our company send push notification from the server side with the APNS token obtained from device, and we are currently migrating over FCM.

**My question is once the user upgrades to the new app using the FCM token, will the old APNS token still work?**

I am asking because the current design of the app has a disconnect and it could wait up to an hour before the device updates the server with the new FCM token.  During that time, the server will continue to send push notifications with the old APNS token, and we want to make sure user is still able to receive them.

If anyone can give any insight on that, that will be great!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes , it will as long as you use the correct device token and uploaded the .pem file but make sure to separate the usual token from FCM token  , regarding firebase you should upload .p12 development & dis files , there is no big deal behind firebase it also sends the push content to apns